# sshd: unrecognized service error

Tags: ssh, services, sshd

In my Ubuntu 12.04 box, my MaxStartups was like this earlier:

```
grep MaxStartups /etc/ssh/sshd_config
#MaxStartups 10:30:60
```

I increased it to 100 and below is the result now:

```
grep MaxStartups /etc/ssh/sshd_config
MaxStartups 100
```

Now after this change, I was trying to restart the `sshd` service like this:

```
david@machineA:~$ sudo service sshd restart
sshd: unrecognized service
```

And every time I am getting this error `sshd: unrecognized service`. Is there anything wrong I am doing?

This is a brand new machine I got from Unix team in our company.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The service is `ssh`, not `sshd`:

```
$ initctl list | grep ssh
ssh start/running, process 1379
```

So, do:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```